# I have problem with the parameters in a query in dataset

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ms-access, dataset

I have a .NET program with a dataset to an access/a sql DB.
I wrote a query and used 2 parameters, but I got an error:

> Error in WHERE clause near '@'.
>   Unable to parse query text.

My  query is:

```
SELECT DocID, DocCustomerNumber, 
    DocSessionID, DocTitle, DocKlaser, DocBarcodes
FROM VTblASMCustomersDocsAndGroupCodes
WHERE DocCustomerNumber = @cusNum AND 
    DocSessionID = @asmNum
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]. We need to see how you are **running** that query.

Comment: Share your table structure, typically that error means that one of the fields is incorrect (maybe a typo?)

Comment: another error text: "missing operator) at the where..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Access doesn't use named parameters. It uses positional parameters. So the order of the parameters is important when you set the values of the parameters.

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT DocID, DocCustomerNumber, 
    DocSessionID, DocTitle, DocKlaser, DocBarcodes
FROM VTblASMCustomersDocsAndGroupCodes
WHERE DocCustomerNumber = ? AND 
    DocSessionID = ?
```

Then use this code to pass the parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", param1); // param1 = value of DocCustomerNumber
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", param2); // param2 = value of DocSessionID
```